# Postgresql Custom Cast Json to text Fails inside UNION ALL in Entity Framework generated SQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

In the model the entity property is string type but this field in the DB is of jsonb.  However, I cannot specify [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")] for the property because the same model is used against other databases where the property field is varchar.  I thought that the simplest solution would be to create a custom cast on the Postgres db so I did something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsoncast(j jsonb)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'    
AS $$
BEGIN
    return jsonb_pretty(j);
END;
$$;

ALTER FUNCTION jsoncast(jsonb)OWNER TO postgres;         
         
CREATE CAST (jsonb AS text)
    WITH FUNCTION jsoncast(j jsonb)
    AS IMPLICIT;
```

However, it does not work when EF sends to the db something like this:

```
...
CAST (NULL AS text) AS "C26", 
...
```

and it cannot processes it telling me that "UNION types jsonb and text cannot be matched"

UPDATE:
The custom cast works but it fails inside of a UNION ALL.